# Angular 4 + play framework

Tags: angular2, playframework

Есть задание, написать приложение play framework + UI на Angular 4.

1) Правильно я понимаю что play разворачивается на своем сервере а Angular на своем, и общаться они должны через http запросы? Это нормально или я что то упускаю?

2) Кто в таком случае отвечает за авторизацию и аутентификацию?